# Prevent browser from closing on touch screen display

Tags: javascript, php, windows, google-chrome, firefox

I have request for creating web app (php/javascript) for coffee shop that will be self service and using windows machine with touch screen display

where people can choose type of coffee, size and so on

the problem is this will run on browser where people can simple click close button (x) and close the browser and next customer wont be able to make orders

I look around to prevent this programmatically but did not found anuthing

Is there anyway to prevent people from closing the browser ? Is there any setting on windows of browser to prevent this ?

Comment: Look for "kiosk mode": e.g. https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/9273974?hl=en

Comment: And here’s the Windows equivalent: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/configuration/kiosk-single-app

Comment: if you are using only a touch screen without an keyboard or mouse, pres F11 on the browser, it will go full screen and hide the minimize and close buttons.

Comment: @Vidal that sound like life hack :) i will try it. Also tnx to everyone